# How to setup Guacamole session recording with RDP and SSH

Tags: ssh, rdp, guacamole

Anyone here helps me out to config guacamole session recording RDP and SSH. I tried too with GUI, but it's not working. Mentioned path files are empty.
is there any setting need to enable in guacamole.properties.
There are no  error logs

[Guacamole WEB gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7QYP.png)

Answer (score 1):

## gucamole Screen recording

create a folder in Gucamole server
mkdir /Connection-Name
chown **dameon.dameon** /Connection-Name

## Web GUI

Existing connection Navigate to Screen Recording option
Recording path: /Connection-Name
Recording name: Connection-name
Include key events: Tick it

Save the connection.

Test sceneraio

Once you saved the connection, Connect the RDP session using guacamole via browser

navigate to /Connection-Name and check the file name called Connection-name

If you want to view the video then you need to Encode the file.
Below Steps to Encode into .m4v

USAGE: guacenc [-s WIDTHxHEIGHT] [-r BITRATE] [-f] [FILE]...

guacenc -s 1280x720 -r 20000000 -f Connection-name

File will generate  Connection-name.4v

Transfer the files into local machine and play with VLC player.

2Mins of session it takes  2.5MB(with out encoded)

Comment: Is there any way to start session recording with common-js and save it into a local machine rather than a remote server or guacd?

Comment: Havent tried it . if got chance i will try with common-js.  Use NFS share  mount on the /connection  .so it can be accessible remotely.